# Does operator precedence works the same way for string as for numbers?

Tags: python, string, operator-precedence

While code golfing I stumbled on a peculiar issue

```
>>> print '%'+'-+'[1]+str(5)+'s'%'*'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#178>", line 1, in <module>
    print '%'+'-+'[1]+str(5)+'s'%'*'
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My assumption was operator evaluation happens from left to right, but in this particular case, it seems that even though its string operation, `%` [takes priority over](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)`+` and tries to evaluate `'s'%'*'` before the concatenation and fails

Is this a known documented behavior, or there is something more that is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#id27).

Precedence is consistent across the language, regardless of the object being operated on. Anything else would be horribly confusing, since it's possible to construct objects with 'operator' special methods - like, for `%`, [`__mod__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mod__) - with arbitrary behaviour. If it were also possible for objects to define their own precedence rules, debugging unexpected results would become much more difficult.